# Python iterator not working as anticipated

Tags: python, generator, iterable

I have the following code, I'm trying to compare some values and return the highest ones:

```
def high(it):
    it = iter(it)
    returnlist = []
    try:
        while True:
            one = next(it)
            two = next(it) 
            three = next(it)
            if three <= two and one <= two:
                returnlist.append(two)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return returnlist
```

It's half working, but not properly:

```
>>high([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]) #(this works)
[1, 8, 5] 
>>high([5,2,4,9,6,1,3,8,0,7]) #(this doesn't work, should return [9,8]
[8] 
>>high(int(is_prime(p)) for p in irange(1,20)) #(doesn't work, returns four 1's - should return 5)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `second` is not defined in your line `return list.append(second)` I am assuming it to be `two` instead of `second`

Comment: Step through the code in your head, you'll see the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that in every iteration of your loop, your iterator advances three positions. So you're just comparing elements [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], etc. NOT every group of adjacent 3.

Comment: What you're doing could be done just by `for one, two, three in zip(it, it, it):`. If you need to iterate over windows instead of chunks, you need to keep track of the last two values somehow, whether explicitly or otherwise. (The `pairwise` recipe in the `itertools` docs demonstrates an easy way to do it implicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing is dividing the "list" into chunks of 3 and only comparing the numbers within each chunk. This means that you're only comparing the first 3 numbers with each other, then the next 3 with each other. What you want to do is to use a sliding window so that every number is compared with the ones next to it. You can do this by keeping track of previous values:

```
def high(lst):
    returnlist = []
    one = None
    two = None
    for three in lst:
        # If one is None here we haven't
        # reached the first set of numbers yet
        if not one is None: 
            if three <= two and one <= two:
                returnlist.append(two)
        # Update the sliding window
        one = two
        two = three
    return returnlist
```

Comment: This is definitely the method I'd prefer, however, it's causing problems for this instance: `high(int(is_prime(p)) for p in irange(1,20))` should equal `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` but returns `[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]` - do you think this could be because of some equality error?

Comment: I don't know from where you get the `is_prime` and `irange` methods so I can't test that case for you

Comment: @unicornication see the last paragraph of my answer.  I think your expectations are incorrect, and Raniz solution is return correctly

Comment: @Raniz  it's a good solution but it's got bugs if there can be `None` values in the list.  Better would have been to initialise the first three values using `next` *before* looping.

Answer (score 1):

@Shashank comment is correct in that you are assuming the iterators are independent, when they are not.  You can patch up your function using `tee`:

```
from itertools import tee

def high(it):

    it1,it2,it3 = tee(iter(it), 3)
    next(it2, None)
    next(it3, None); next(it3, None)

    returnlist = []
    try:
        while True:
            one = next(it1)
            two = next(it2) 
            three = next(it3)
            if three <= two and one <= two:
                returnlist.append(two)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return returnlist
```

What I think is a more pythonic way of implementing the same idea:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def threesome(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1,s2), (s1,s2,s3), (s2,s3,s4), ..."
    a, b, c = tee(iterable, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None); next(c, None)
    return izip(a, b, c)

def high(it):
    return [x2 for x1, x2, x3 in threesome(it) if x2 == max(x1, x2, x3)]
```

By the way, I think your expected output for the last case is incorrect.  You should see zeroes in the output aswell, because this will happen anytime you have three composite numbers in a row (e.g. 8,9,10 will satisfy your conditions).